# In HttpSession session = request.getSession(); Where is the "request" object defined?

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Using twitter4j and java, I am trying to use the following code to connect to Twitter. In my  java class I have the following code.

```
Twitter twitter = new Twitter();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey,consumerSecret);
RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

String token = requestToken.getToken();
String tokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("token",token);
session.setAttribute("tokenSecret",tokenSecret);
```

I got this code from a tutorial. The problem I am having is with the line

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Where is the object "request" defined?

My program is a localhost program, entirely in Java. I am trying to learn how to use the Twitter API

Comment: I have the same question except I've got a JSP file and am not extending HttpServlet 
 (afaik)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a question that you should be answering yourself. It looks like your tutorial assumed it was running from a Servlet or JSP, where there's an [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object available that looks like it would fill those roles. The only reason it seems to be used, though, is because the HTTP session is a convenient place to store the oauth token and secret in a webapp. You can put them anywhere as long as you can get them back later.

Comment: "You should answer it yourself". That's hardly going to help he and I figure out where "request" is instantiated.